# How do I get the current Unix time in milliseconds in Bash?

Tags: bash, unix, time

How do I get the current Unix time in milliseconds (i.e number of milliseconds since Unix epoch January 1 1970)?

Answer (score 441, accepted):

#### This:

```
date +%s
```

will return the number of *seconds* since the epoch.

#### This:

```
date +%s%N
```

returns the seconds and current nanoseconds.

#### So:

```
date +%s%N | cut -b1-13
```

will give you the number of milliseconds since the epoch - current seconds plus the left three of the nanoseconds.

---

and from [MikeyB](https://serverfault.com/users/2101/mikeyb) - `echo $(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))` (dividing by 1000 only brings to microseconds)

Comment: I wonder how many ms the cut adds :-)

Comment: you're looking at screen refresh time - that's already going to add *something* :)

Comment: I think seconds * 1000 will be fine :)

Comment: Or if you want to do it all in the shell, avoiding the expensive overhead of an additional process (actually, we're avoiding the problem when the number of digits in %+s+N changes): `echo $(($(date +%s%N)/1000))`

Comment: @MikeyB - when will the number of digits change? we're only in the single digit billions for seconds now.. which means at least another 7x40 years before it'd be something to worry about, no? (Presuming, of course, we don't hit the Unix time wall first)

Comment: It's the principle of the matter... avoid magic numbers and code what you actually *mean*.

Comment: then technically yours has magic numbers, too :)

Comment: I think it's worth noting that the man asked for Unix, not Linux, and the current top answer (date +%s%N) doesn't work on my AIX system.

Comment: @Pete +1 Same for OS X, and FreeBSD

Comment: I think it is important to note that the division does **NOT** give you the milliseconds! You need to divide by 1,000,000! *(Since 1s is 1,000,000,000ns and 1s is 1000ms. Therefore 1ms is 1,000,000ns)*

Comment: @BrainStone - the division option *is* dividing by 1,000,000

Comment: @warren Youn are right. I was reffering to the one in the comments. I did not see the one in the answer...

Comment: `%N` does not work on OSX Yosemite

Comment: @MattClark - there doesn't seem to be a format specifier for the BSD `date` command for nanoseconds

Comment: on OS X your best bet might be brew coreutils, then you can `gdate +%s%N`

Comment: The last option does not work on OS X:
echo $(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))
-bash: 1448370039N: value too great for base (error token is "1448370039N")

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics) Even if you do all kinds of tricks moving away all kinds of additional processes, the time used for moving the calculation to other cores/threads still count! (OCD)

Comment: Instead of using `cut -b1-13`, one could use the bash substring: `dt=$(date +%s%N); ${dt:1:13}`.

Comment: If you are doing math to adjust the order of magnitude after specifying a format, you are doing it wrong. [Joe did it the right way](https://serverfault.com/a/588705/4131).

Comment: Would this not work on macOs? echo $(($(date +%s)*1000))

Comment: @BrillPappin - no. That multiplies the current *seconds* by 1000.

Comment: @warren yes exactly, if he's asking for milliseconds, then 1 second == 1000 milliseconds, as far as I remember.

Comment: @BrillPappin - but merely *multiplying* seconds by 1000 doesn't give "current Unix time in milliseconds": it gives you "the current second as if it were milliseconds". In other words, You won't get 1598360260075 or 1598360260901. You would get 1598360260000. Your method will be somewhere between "exactly correct" and "off by as much as 999 milliseconds". If *millisecond precision* is necessary (a pretty common use case), then being off by as much as 999ms is totally unacceptable :)

Comment: @warren ahh, of course, makes sense :) you still need to know what those fractions of a second are.

Comment: Shouldn't this: `date +%s%N` actually be this, to insert the decimal between the seconds and nanoseconds?: `date +%s.%N`

Comment: @GabrielStaples - if you wanted the decimal, probably. But that's not what OP asked for (when I answered)

Answer (score 200):

You may simply use `%3N` to truncate the nanoseconds to the 3 most significant digits (which then are milliseconds):

```
$ date +%s%3N
1397392146866
```

This works e.g. on my [Kubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubuntu) 12.04 (Precise Pangolin).

But be aware that `%N` may not be implemented depending on your target system. E.g. tested on an embedded system (buildroot rootfs, compiled using a non-HF ARM cross toolchain) there was no `%N`:

```
$ date +%s%3N
1397392146%3N
```

(And also my (non rooted) Android tablet doesn't have `%N`.)

Comment: @warren: I saw that you edited and changed the `1397392146%3N` to `1397392146%N`, but the output of `1397392146%3N` is that what I'd really seen on the busybox console of my android tablet. Could you explain your edit?

Comment: warren's comment from the history is "changed from 3 to 6, as 3 only takes you to microseconds". His edit seems entirely spurious; you should roll it back.

Comment: This is a feature of GNU coreutils specifically. Ultimately, this is implemented in gnulib here: https://github.com/gagern/gnulib/blob/71090a2a314d9c378afd6f842abb49f60b42d4ef/lib/strftime.c#L1085.

Comment: probably a dot in there makes sense. `date +%s.%3N` prints `1510718281.134`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: What is *"HF"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Hard Float. ARM CPUs with hardware support for floating point numbers, as opposed to Soft Float where that has to be done slowly in software.

Answer (score 96):

`date +%N` doesn't work on OS X, but you could use one of

- [Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29): `ruby -e 'puts Time.now.to_f'`
- [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29): `python -c 'import time; print(int(time.time() * 1000))'`
- [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js): `node -e 'console.log(Date.now())'`
- [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP): `php -r 'echo microtime(TRUE);'`
- [Elixir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elixir_(programming_language)): `DateTime.utc_now() |> DateTime.to_unix(:millisecond)`
- The Internet: `wget -qO- http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now?\\s.\\N`
- or for milliseconds rounded to nearest second `date +%s000`

Comment: for completeness... `node -e 'console.log(Date.now())'`

Comment: Using PHP: `php -r 'echo microtime(TRUE);'`

Comment: Sure, you just have to wait for those interpreters to warm up. This works, too: `wget -qO- http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now?\\s.\\N`

Comment: Or, if you *don't actually need the milliseconds* but just the correct format: `date +%s000`

Comment: @CamiloMartin: I love your (tongue-in-cheek?) wget exemple to get milliseconds precision out of a (remote) request to a website ^^. Locally, a few of the examples above are indeed probably closer to the tenth-of-a-second or maybe hundredth-of-a-second precision

Comment: @OlivierDulac yes, I wouldn't recommend that seriously! That said, it's [far too common](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/29zx7z/) to see code that would break if someone, somewhere, decided to have some fun. Also, tenth-of-a-second?! In reality you can take the fractional part and redirect it to `/dev/random` to improve the system's entropy pool.

Comment: Perl: `echo "1487787384024" | perl -MTime::Piece -pe 's/(\d{13})/Time::Piece->localtime($1 \/1000)->strftime("%Y-%m-%d %a")/e'` . The nice thing about this is that you can feed a whole line of text containing a 13-digit timestamp and it will perform a substitution and leave the rest of the text as-is

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135742/time-in-milliseconds-since-epoch-in-the-terminal has instructions for doing this in OSX via Brew's `coreutils`

Comment: As @sameers pointed out: you can install `coreutils` on macOS with `brew install coreutils` and then `gdate +%N` will work.

Comment: this is an amazing answer

Answer (score 29):

My solution is not the best, but it worked for me:

```
date +%s000
```

I just needed to convert a date like 2012-05-05 to milliseconds.

Answer (score 12):

Just throwing this out there, but I think the correct formula with the division would be:

```
echo $(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))
```

Answer (score 8):

For the people that suggest running external programs to get the **milli**seconds... at that rate, you might as well do this:

```
wget -qO- http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now?\\s.\\N
```

Point being: before picking any answer from here, please keep in mind that not all programs will run under one whole second. Measure!

Comment: You're not asking the local system for the time. Which I guess is implied in the question. You also depend on a network connection.

Comment: @orkoden The question explicitly asks for "number of milliseconds since Unix epoch January 1 1970". Also, I'm more of pointing out how you shouldn't ever fire up whole of Ruby or Python (or wget) just to get the time - either this is done through a fast channel or milliseconds don't matter.

Comment: Yes, I understood that you were giving a worse solution to highlight the bad solutions' flaws. I tried several solutions and measured the time. http://lpaste.net/119499 The results are kind of interesting. Even on a very fast i7 machine `date` takes 3 ms to run.

Comment: @orkoden Nice testing! What OS? This might have to do with process spawning overhead.

Comment: I used OS X 10.10.2.

Comment: @orkoden Complementing that with a couple other platforms: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=q6Y6Beaj

Comment: You're running `date` twice and then subtracting, while also using `awk`. This seems to be inexact, because `awk` also takes up some of that time. Why aren't you using `time`?

Comment: @orkoden Both are run one next to the other in `bash`'s "command substitution" phase, and when `awk` sees them, they're just literal values. If you assume running `date` will always take about the same time (which it seems to be), the difference between when one value was ready vs. when the next value was ready will give you the run time of `date` itself. `time` gives me way more fluctuation than doing this so I guess `time` is not very precise.

Comment: It's already dead.

Comment: @Nakilon and this is why one shouldn't rely on curl-able conveniences like those for anything production.

Comment: Perfect, *Ctrl-c*, open production code, *Ctrl-v*

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for a way to display the length of time your script ran, the following will provide a (not completely accurate) result:

As near the beginning of your script as you can, enter the following

`basetime=$(date +%s%N)`

This'll give you a starting value of something like 1361802943996000000.

At the end of your script, use the following

`echo "runtime: $(echo "scale=3;($(date +%s%N) - ${basetime})/(1*10^09)" | bc) seconds"`

which will display something like

`runtime: 12.383 seconds`

Notes:

(1*10^09) can be replaced with 1000000000 if you wish

`"scale=3"` is a rather rare setting that coerces `bc` to do what you want. There are lots more!

I only tested this on Windows 7/MinGW... I don't have a proper *nix box at hand.

Comment: or you could just use `time <script>`

Answer (score 5):

### Another solution for MacOS: GNU Coreutils

I have noticed that the MacOS' version of the `date` command is not interpreting the `%N` format sequence as nanoseconds but simply prints `N` to the output when I started using [my `.bashrc` script](https://github.com/ferenczy/dotfiles/blob/d7d70d3410046dd2a035d8f46c577c64818f1f2f/.bashrc#L163) from Linux, that's using it to measure how long executed commands run, on a MacOS machine.

After a little bit of research, I have learned that only the GNU date from the [GNU Coreutils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities) package [does support milliseconds](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html). Fortunately, it's pretty easy to install it on MacOS using Homebrew:

```
brew install coreutils
```

Since that package contains executables that are already present on MacOS, Coreutils' executables will be installed with a `g` prefix, so `date` will be available as `gdate`.

See for example [this page](https://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/) for further details.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to get time in milliseconds without performing division. Maybe it's faster...

```
# test=`date +%s%N`
# testnum=${#test}
# echo ${test:0:$testnum-6}
1297327781715
```

Update: Another alternative in pure Bash that works only with Bash 4.2+ is the same as above, but use `printf` to get the date. It will definitely be faster, because no processes are forked off the main one.

```
printf -v test '%(%s%N)T' -1
testnum=${#test}
echo ${test:0:$testnum-6}
```

Another catch here though is that your `strftime` implementation should support `%s` and `%N` which is *not* the case on my test machine. See `man strftime` for supported options. Also see `man bash` to see `printf` syntax. `-1` and `-2` are special values for time.

Comment: Seems like my `strftime(3)` doesn't support `%N` so no way for `printf` to print nanoseconds. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @haridsv, yeah, it's not in glibc. `date` seems like the more reliable option.

Answer (score 2):

(repeat from previous answers) `date +%N` doesn't work on OS X, but you could also use:

Perl (requires Time::Format module). Perhaps it is not the best [CPAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPAN) module to use, but it gets the job done. Time::Format is generally made available with distributions.

```
perl -w -e'use Time::Format; printf STDOUT ("%s.%s\n", time, $time{"mmm"})'
```

Comment: The OP specifically asked for ways to do it using bash.  How is this bash, save as a method to launch something else?

Comment: I use this in my bash shell scripts ... under OSX. So, `date` can't be used and there is no bash-only commands that answer the need.

Comment: Fair enough.  If you were to clarify why OSX's `date` can't be used **as part of your answer**, I'd remove my downvote.

Comment: This was explained a few answers above. I couldn't add as comment that command which was missing with the proposed list. So I've added it here.

Comment: Fair enough, I accept this is a useful addition to the canon.  +1 from me!

Answer (score 2):

The most accurate timestamp we can get for Mac OS X is probably this:

```
python3 -c 'import datetime; print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%s.%f"))'

1490665305.021699
```

But we need to keep in mind that it takes around 30 milliseconds to run.
We can cut it to the scale of 2 digits fraction, and at the very beginning compute the **average overhead** of reading the time, and then remove it off the measurement. Here is an example:

```
function getTimestamp {
  echo `python -c 'import datetime; print datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%s.%f")' | cut -b1-13` 
}
function getDiff {
  echo "$2-$1-$MeasuringCost" | bc
}
prev_a=`getTimestamp`
acc=0
ITERATIONS=30
for i in `seq 1 $ITERATIONS`;do 
  #echo -n $i 
  a=`getTimestamp`
  #echo -n "   $a"
  b=`echo "$a-$prev_a" | bc`
  prev_a=$a
  #echo "  diff=$b"
  acc=`echo "$acc+$b" | bc`
done
MeasuringCost=`echo "scale=2; $acc/$ITERATIONS" | bc`
echo "average: $MeasuringCost sec"
t1=`getTimestamp`
sleep 2
t2=`getTimestamp`
echo "measured seconds: `getDiff $t1 $t2`"
```

You can uncomment the echo commands to see better how it works.

The results for this script are usually one of these 3 results:

```
measured seconds: 1.99
measured seconds: 2.00
measured seconds: 2.01
```

Answer (score 2):

For [Alpine Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux) (many Docker images) and possibly other minimal Linux environments, you can abuse `adjtimex`:

```sh
adjtimex | awk '/(time.tv_usec):/ { printf("%06d\n", $2) }' | head -c3
```

`adjtimex` is used to read (and set) kernel time variables. With `awk` you can get the microseconds, and with `head` you can use the first 3 digits only.

I have no idea how reliable this command is.

Note: Shamelessly stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548528/command-to-get-time-in-milliseconds/38872276#38872276)

Comment: `adjtimex` returns `adjtimex: Function not implemented` under Alpine for me.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/ysoftwareab/nanoseconds

I've just created this cross-platform project via golang to output nanoseconds since Unix epoch. As simple as that. Download your-platform-of-choice executable from a Github release.

Getting granular timestamps is important for benchmarks (e.g. OpenTelemetry). Depending on GNU/coreutils/insert-programming-language is in many cases a no go.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This binary is ~3X faster than the python solution on my machine (10-12ms, vs 30ms with python). It runs with roughly the same speed as `date +%s%N`. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

Additional solution since this question was originally asked in 2014. Bash 5.0 (released 2019) introduced two new [built in variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html)

EPOCHREALTIME - The number of seconds since the Unix Epoch as a floating point value with micro-second granularity

EPOCHSECONDS - The number of seconds since the Unix Epoch

To obtain milliseconds since the Epoch, you can truncate the last three digits of microseconds to get milliseconds with `${EPOCHREALTIME::-3}` and avoid the (expensive) call to `date` or other external programs.

Answer (score 1):

Using date and expr can get you there
i.e.

```
X=$(expr \`date +%H\` \\* 3600 + \`date +%M\` \\* 60 + \`date +%S\`)
echo $X
```

Just expand on it to do whatever you want

I realise this does not give milliseconds since epoch, but it might still be useful as an answer for some of the cases, it all depends on what you need it for really, multiply by 1000 if you need a millisecond number :D

Simplest way would be to make a small executable (from C f.ex.) and make it available to the script.

Comment: There's a potential problem running `date` multiple times. In some cases, the date or time may change between runs as your command is written. It's better to run `date` once and parse the parts out and do your calculation. One of several ways to do that would be `t=$(date +%H%M%S); (( x = ${t:0:2} * 3600 + ${t:2:2} * 60 + ${t:4:2} )); echo "$x"`. This uses Bash syntax since the question is tagged [tag:bash]. As you allude, your answer (and my variation) only gives seconds for the current day so far and not since the Epoch and not in millis.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the previous responses all together, when in OS X,

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion:    10.11.6
BuildVersion:    15G31+
```

you can do like

```
microtime() {
    python -c 'import time; print time.time()'
}
compute() {
    local START="$(microtime)"
    #$1 is command $2 are args
    local END="$(microtime)"
    DIFF="$(bc <<< "$END - $START")"
    echo "$1\t$2\t$DIFF"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not adding anything revolutionary here over the accepted answer, but just to make it reusable easily for those of you whom are newer to Bash. Note that this example works in OS X  and on older Bash which was a requirement for me personally.

```
nowInMs() {
  echo "$(($(date +'%s * 1000 + %-N / 1000000')))"
}
```

Now you can run

```
TIMESTAMP="$(nowInMs)";
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `$(brew --prefix)/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin` in your `$PATH`?  
  
On my macOS 12.7: `/bin/date +'%s * 1000 + %-N / 1000000'` gives `1710943086 * 1000 + N / 1000000`  
  
Only the gnu version interprets `%N`:  `$(brew --prefix)/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/date +'%s * 1000 + %-N / 1000000'` to give `1710943233 * 1000 + 044024 / 1000000`

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution

`perl -mTime::HiRes -e 'printf "%.0f\n", (Time::HiRes::time() * 1000 )'`

Time::HiRes::time() returns a float of the form unixtimeinsec.microseconds

Multiply by 1000 to shift left 3 digits, and output with no decimal digits.
Why not just convert to integer with %d?
Because it'll overflow a signed (or unsigned) integer on a 32 bit OS, such
as our ancient AIX servers.

As others have pointed out, it's a question of portability.  The accepted answer works on linux or anything that can run gnu date, but not on several other UNIX flavors.  Personally I find our older systems are much more likely to have perl than python,  Node.js, Ruby or PHP.

Yes, `date +%s%3N`   (if available) is about 5x faster than perl).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple shell elapsed computation, this is easy and portable, using [Frank Thonig's answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/151109/how-do-i-get-the-current-unix-time-in-milliseconds-in-bash/895707#895707):

```
now() {
    python -c 'import datetime; print datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%s.%f")'
}
seismo:~$ x=`now`
seismo:~$ y=`now`
seismo:~$ bc <<< "$y - $x"
5.212514
```